# No GUI on ubuntu 12.04 Server after install ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 12.04, server, desktop-environments

I just got a dedicated server from hosting company and I want to use a GUI Desktop *(Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 + x2go 64-bit system)*. So I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

I then install VNC: `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver` and run VNC. But I only see the terminal, not the GUI.

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you don't have an X server running yet; try running `startx` and see if that works.